# Choosing pandas over xlsxwriter when working with Excel data

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

Since Pandas uses the xlsxwriter module, why bother using Pandas when one can just use xlsxwriter directly?

Maybe a more direct question to answer is, why should one consider replacing xlsxwriter with Pandas when working with excel data?

My goal with this question is to help one decide whether to use xlsxwriter or Pandas when working with Excel data.

Comment: Well, the functionality of pandas goes way way way way way beyond writing and reading excel file

Comment: Yep, that I do understand.  The question is focused specifically on working w/ excel data.  I'm hoping to expose features that are available in Pandas that are simply not available in xlsxwriter that would warrant one to decide to just using Pandas when working with excel (e.g. something like "Pandas is able to handle null o empty data better than xlsxwriter")

Comment: depends on your requirements "*Pandas is a Python library for data manipulation and analysis, e.g. dataframes, multidimensional time series and cross-sectional datasets commonly found in statistics, experimental science results, econometrics, or finance. Pandas is one of the main data-science libraries in Python.*"-- taken from the tag description, your edit makes the question very broad..!!

Comment: @lobi just to name a few: data merging(joining/alignment), subsetting, reshaping (melt/pivot), aggregation and transformation (groupby), visualisation (plot), handling missing data/ time series handling (resampling) / IO (excel/parquet/csv/stata...) etc. Are you going to use xlsxwriter to do all of these....?

Comment: I wrote XlsxWriter and some of the backend to plug it into Pandas. I would say that Pandas has a much wider scope than XlsxWriter. If you only need to write Excel files, and need/want tight control over the layout then XlsxWriter will suit your needs (or OpenPyXL). If you need to manipulated your data before dumping it to Excel (and 100 other features) then Pandas is the tool to choose. You can easily [mix and match both modules](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) anyway.

Comment: @jmcnamara Just casually running into people who literally wrote the tools you're using right now. This is why i love SO :) Thank you for your contributions!

Comment: ^ Seriously.  Extremely amazing to have jmcnamara himself respond.  I may re-write my question based off jmcnamara's comment + the fact that it was "put on hold"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One word: **convenience**. Reading and writing from/to Excel spreadsheet is a *very* common task when dealing with data. As an example, here's how to create a dead-simple Excel file from [`xlsxwriter` tutorial](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html):

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```

Compare that to pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Amount': [1000, 100, 300, 50]
}, index=['Rent', 'Gas', 'Food', 'Gym'])
df.loc['Total', 'Amount'] = df['Amount'].sum()

df.to_excel('Expenses01.xlsx', index=False)
```

They are not exactly equal of course. `xlsxwriter` creates a formula for the sum, but the amount of boilerplatte code you have to write is montrous. `df.to_excel` is a simple command that dumps the dataframe to Excel. You have little control over the resultant file but depending on your requirements, you may not even need that.

They are two libraries designed for 2 totally different purposes. pandas provide an integration with `xlsxwriter` doesn't mean that you should pick one over the other all the times. Use `df.to_excel` when you need convenience and `xlsxwriter` when you want fine control.

Comment: *the amount of boilerplatte code you have to write is montrous.* In fairness, that code is taken from a tutorial and thus overly verbose. :-) You could write the data with 5 lines of code if succinctness was the goal. Apart from that I agree that the libraries are designed for different purposes and the choice depends on the task in hand.