# Is there a way of writing a formula to the .xlsx file just with pandas, i.e. without using tools like xlsxwriter / openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I wrote a script that reads [this .xlsx file](https://pbpython.com/extras/excel-comp-data.xlsx), then creates a column that is the sum of the three other columns, and saves everything into a new file:

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.read_excel("excel-comp-data.xlsx")

df["total"] = df["Jan"] + df["Feb"] + df["Mar"]

df.to_excel("excel-comp-data-formula-by-pandas.xlsx")
```

The issue with this code is that it does not create a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula), it just adds everything up and places the result in the newly created column.

When I later access the newly created file in [libreoffice calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Calc)
and manually modify any data in "Jan", "Feb", or "March" the corresponding data in the column "total" does not get updated.

I've have found [some code snippets on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648069/choosing-pandas-over-xlsxwriter-when-working-with-excel-data) that create formulas, but all of them use tools as `xlsxwriter`. How might I create a formula in `pandas` without using such tools?

Is it at all doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How might I create a formula in pandas without using such tools?

Pandas uses xlsxwriter (or openpyxl) to create xlsx file so you are already using them.

You can add formulas, instead of a static sum, like this:

```py
import pandas 

df = pandas.read_excel("excel-comp-data.xlsx")

df["total"] = [f'=SUM(H{row}:J{row})' for row in range(2, df.shape[0] + 2)]

df.to_excel("excel-comp-data-formula-by-pandas.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Output:

[image]

Excel gives a formula warning (green triangle) since it thinks, incorrectly, that you should be adding column G to the formula as well. Hopefully you can just ignore that, or switch columns F and G in the dataframe.

It probably also works with openpyxl as an engine as well.

Comment: Works fine, thanks. As a side note, it works out of the box on docs.google.com. That said, `libreoffice` displays all the results in the new column as 0 (the formula is still there). 
When you then modify any value from the columns being added 
up by the formula, the result in the corresponding row of 'total' is displayed correctly. Using `xlsxwriter` instead of `pandas`
as tool doesn't mitigate this issue - it seems to be related to `libreoffice`.

Comment: That is a known issue (mainly in libreoffice but xlsxwriter plays a part as well). It is possible to work around it when using xlsxwriter directly but not through Pandas. See the following FAQ in the xlsxwriter docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-why-do-my-formulas-show-a-zero-result-in-some-non-excel-applications